# How to connect an Azure Functions project to local Cosmos DB?

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I'm creating an Azure function that is going to perform a GET request for a document in CosmosDB. I initialized a new Azure Functions project in Visual Studio 2019 preview, created a new HTTP Trigger function, and now am struggling to connect to my Azure Cosmos emulator. The emulator gives me a primary connection string, but I'm not sure how it's read in. I want to go to the function url and have it return the data I put in my local Cosmos emulator. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To connect to the local emulator you just create a new Cosmos client instance with this endpoint and key.

```
CosmosClient client = new CosmosClient("https://localhost:8081", "C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw==");
```

hope this is helpful.

Comment: Please make sure to make the client a singleton/static https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/manage-connections#static-clients and don't create a new client for each execution.